How to pass expanded/collapsed state of Mui-Accordion to child components?
I am using Mui accordion in the following manner:
<Accordion
  defaultExpanded
>
  <AccordionSummary
    expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}
    aria-controls="panel-content"
  >
    <Box width={"100%"}>
      <Typography variant="h6">{`Insights`}</Typography>
      <Divider sx={{ mb: 2 }} />
    </Box>
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
    ....
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>


all the compoenents in the code are from Mui.

I want to render that Divider only when the Accordion is expanded, how do I manage or get that expanded/collapsed state of Accordion without using any extra state variable?
Is there any way provided by Mui out of the box to get expanded state?
It is expected that the Divider only renders in expanded state without using any extra varible to maintain current state of Divider
